How to connect signals from a child node in the script of a root node?
Let's suppose that we have a tree of nodes like this:

There's a script attached to the root node (GreenTower). What are the other ways to connect two signals (body_entered and body_exited) from Area2D (TowerDetectionArea) in the GreenTower script?
I know we can export a variable and pass that node to the script, but suppose we have different nodes like TowerDetectionArea or even nodes in a different scene that need their signals defined in the same script.
[Export]
private Area2D _towerDetectionArea;

public override void _Ready()
{
     _towerDetectionArea.Connect(Area2D.SignalName.BodyEntered, new Callable(this,MethodName.OnTowerDetectionAreaBodyEntered));
}


You're pretty close to the right idea. Since you know the tree node hierarchy, you don't need to set the variable as an export variable. You can do something like below.
private Area2D towerDetectionArea;

public override void _Ready()
{
    towerDetectionArea = GetNode<Area2d>("TowerDetectionArea");
    towerDetectionArea.BodyEntered += HandleTowerDetectionBodyEntered;
}

private void HandleTowerDetectionBodyEntered(Body2D body)
{
    // Do stuff
}

Keep in mind, my Godot C# knowledge is with Godot 3, I have mainly used GDScript with Godot 4.
That said, you connect to children nodes via the GetNode function and give the path from the current node to the child node. Then for signals, you're using C# events. You can see more detailed info on their docs. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_signals.html
Let me know if this helps!

Thanks for your help. The thing is, I don't like having a lot of these hardcoded strings in my code. That's why I said I'd rather export it.

Yeah, the hardcoded strings for the path aren't the best, but I think you'll have to get used to it with C# Godot. GDScript has on-ready variables that are a bit cleaner, but it's a similar setup.
The problem with using Export variables for everything is it's somewhat defeating the composition like structure of Godot. That's not to say Export variables are bad, but they should be used for properties specific to that node, not to replace children nodes, IMO.

maybe you can use eventBus.
create script with some signal in it and put in autoload.
in GDScript i usualy do it like this
extend Node
signal somesignal(text:String)

put that on auto load an call it EvenBus
and in area2d script add this
func _on_body_enter(body):
   EventBus.somesignal.emit(body.name)

and in what ever node need to connect to that signal add this script on func _ready
func _ready():
    EventBus.somesignal.connect(your_function)

for more detail just check EventBus on Youtube tutorial
